# Very Slow Mysql SELECT query

Tags: mysql

ive been struggling with this for a while. its taking over 12 seconds and cant figure out why, its become a lot slower as all three tables have gown.

```
SELECT SUM(quantity), rprice, media_file, url, title
FROM inventory, ndxz_objects, ndxz_media
WHERE productid = ndxz_objects.id
AND media_ref_id = ndxz_objects.id
AND productid = media_ref_id
AND media_order = (SELECT MIN(media_order) FROM ndxz_media WHERE media_ref_id = ndxz_objects.id )
GROUP BY productid
ORDER BY productid DESC
```

Theres is an index on `ndxz_objects.id`and `productid`

Comment: what does explain(.. your_query_here..) say? maybe paste it here so we can get a better idea of where is performance going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the slowdown is caused by the nested query because a table scan is required for each media_ref_id = ndxz_objects.id

you need to create an index on media_ref_id and on media_order in the ndxz_media table

i also suggest to rewrite the query using joins instead

Comment: those indexed helped a lot 0.0022, funny i tried indexes on one but not both before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you also need, at a bare minimum, an index on `ndxz_media.media_ref_id`. (I'm also guessing that that's where the `media_ref_id` column comes from, since you don't scope column-names very clearly.)

The same index should probably include media_order as a second column.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is almost certainly the **correlated** subquery, which is executed once per row, even with an index such queries aren't great. I think the below should achieve the same results.

```
SELECT SUM(quantity), rprice, media_file, url, title
FROM inventory, ndxz_objects, ndxz_media,
(SELECT MIN(media_order) as order FROM ndxz_media GROUP BY media_ref_id) min_orders
WHERE productid = ndxz_objects.id
AND media_ref_id = ndxz_objects.id
AND productid = media_ref_id
AND media_order = min_orders.order 
GROUP BY productid
ORDER BY productid DESC
```

Although the query you provided is actually not valid anyway since `rprice, media_file, url, title` are not aggregated or in the group by clause

Comment: would including rprice, media_file, url, title in the group by clause help?